# Is it possible to move messages from one Azure Topic Subscription to the another?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

We have a scenario where we need to move the existing active messages in one of our existing Topic subscriptions to another topic. Is it possible to do it in Azure Portal?

Any helps will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up auto-forwarding on the subscriptions and point to another topic. This will guarantee all messages received by these subscriptions will be auto-forwarded to the new topic.

> Is it possible to do it in Azure Portal?

Currently, it is not possible to do this on the portal. The functionality is still not available. You can use any of the 3rd party tools to do achieve it. Alternatively, you can script it as well using Azure PowerShell cmdlets or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/topic/subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-topic-subscription-update). The latter would use `az servicebus topic subscription update` command with `--forward-to` option.